# Getting Guru Meditation Error when using DallasTemperature with Wifi.h on esp32

Tags: c++, esp32, arduino-ide

I'm getting this error, when trying to use Wifi + DallasTemperature && OneWire on my esp32. Temperature sensor is Gravity DS18B20.

When I don't use Wifi it works fine.

This is an error code

```
09:41:17.049 -> Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
09:41:17.082 -> 
09:41:17.082 -> Core  1 register dump:
09:41:17.082 -> PC      : 0x400d3b40  PS      : 0x00060433  A0      : 0x800d4488  A1      : 0x3ffb2710  
09:41:17.082 -> A2      : 0x3f40af28  A3      : 0x0000001c  A4      : 0x0a4c4c55  A5      : 0x3ff49000  
09:41:17.082 -> A6      : 0x00000020  A7      : 0x00000000  A8      : 0x800d3b15  A9      : 0x3ffb26d0  
09:41:17.082 -> A10     : 0x00060420  A11     : 0x3ffc2cac  A12     : 0x3ffc2ca4  A13     : 0xb33fffff  
09:41:17.082 -> A14     : 0x00000001  A15     : 0x00000001  SAR     : 0x00000020  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
09:41:17.115 -> EXCVADDR: 0x0a4c4c55  LBEG    : 0x400df328  LEND    : 0x400df332  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  
09:41:17.115 -> 
09:41:17.115 -> 
09:41:17.115 -> Backtrace:0x400d3b3d:0x3ffb27100x400d4485:0x3ffb2750 0x400d476c:0x3ffb2780 0x400d2782:0x3ffb27b0 0x400d53b7:0x3ffb2820
```

Here I have it decoded

```
Decoding 5 results
0x400d3b3d: OneWire::reset() at /home/suomi/Arduino/libraries/OneWire/util/OneWire_direct_gpio.h line 165
:  (inlined by) OneWire::reset() at /home/suomi/Arduino/libraries/OneWire/OneWire.cpp line 172
0x400d4485: OneWire::search(unsigned char*, bool) at /home/suomi/Arduino/libraries/OneWire/OneWire.cpp line 388
0x400d476c: DallasTemperature::begin() at /home/suomi/Arduino/libraries/DallasTemperature/DallasTemperature.cpp line 113
0x400d2782: setup() at /home/suomi/Arduino/sketch_sep18a/sketch_sep18a.ino line 53
0x400d53b7: loopTask(void*) at /home/suomi/.arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/2.0.0/cores/esp32/main.cpp line 38
```

also with backtracked lines in the files mentioned above

```
1. ESP_REG(rtc_reg) = ESP_REG(rtc_reg) & ~(rtc_io_desc[pin].mux);

2. DIRECT_MODE_INPUT(reg, mask);

3.if (!reset()) {

4.while (_wire->search(deviceAddress)) {

5.sensors.begin();

6.void loopTask(void *pvParameters)
{
    setup();
```

And my executed code

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <WiFi.h>


// Wifi Settings
#define WIFI_NETWORK "name"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "pass"
#define WIFI_TIMOUT_MS 20000

const int oneWireBus = 32;
OneWire oneWire(oneWireBus);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
int status;



int connectToWiFi() {
    Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.print("Connencting to WiFi");
    Serial.print(" ");
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_NETWORK, WIFI_PASSWORD);

    unsigned long startAttemptTime = millis();

    while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && millis() - startAttemptTime < WIFI_TIMOUT_MS) {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(700);
    }

    if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.println("Failed connect to WiFi!");
        return 0;

    }

    else {
        Serial.print("Connected to WiFi");
        Serial.println(WIFI_NETWORK);
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
        return 1;
    }
}


void setup() {
    status = connectToWiFi();
    Serial.begin(115200);
    sensors.begin();


void loop() {
        
}
```

I'm not very good in c++, could someone please help me? `LoadProhibited`: It looks like it trying to access a memory that it shouldn't?

Comment: You may want to see if you can get this migrated to [arduino.stackexchange.com](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I used Arduino libs on ESP32. Maybe `Serial.begin()` should be called before `connectToWifi()` because you call Serial methods before initializing it.